# Do I run '''grunt build''' after installing a bower component

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, bower, bower-install

I'm pretty new to grunt & npm etc but I'll explain what my question is as best I can.

I've got a local Wordpress project running with [FoundationPress](http://foundationpress.olefredrik.com/) as the theme. I have grunt running etc.

I have just installed [Foundation Datepicker](https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker) via 'bower'. From the terminal it looks like everything went well and the Foundation Datepicker files are in my bower_components/ folder.

**However I'm not sure if I should be changing directory to the bower_components/foundation-datepicker/ folder and running 'grunt build' command in that directory to "install" the datepicker?** That folder does have a Gruntfile.js in it.

After installing Foundation Datepicker I did run 'grunt build', however that was in the theme folder, so I don't know if that would of picked up the newly downloaded Foundation Datepicker and installed/built that too.

It does say on the GitHub page towards the bottom that I should do a 'grunt build'. Please see here again: https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker

Thanks guys.

Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see `.bowerrc` file in the project

In the `.bowerrc` file, you should have the path like `bower_components/folder` as you want or `bower_components/foundation-datepicker/folder`

Probable solution - 
Make a file named `.bowerrc` at the root level and put the path there as

`{
  "directory" : "js"  //according to your present "foundation-datepicker.js" file location
 }`

Comment: @daniel blythe did you try this ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. There is a bowerrc file in my theme folder and it has the following in it:

{
  "directory": "bower_components"
}. But no I haven't done your suggestion as I already have a bowerrc file there.

Comment: Also how could you of seen whether or not I had a .bowerrc file? FYI I can see file starting with . as I've turned it on in the terminal of my Mac.

Comment: I mean your repo what you have mentioned here. There I didn't find.
If you have the `.bowerrc` file then just put there `"js"` folder path according to your project folder structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. So my .bowerrc file looks like the following: {
  "directory": "bower_components"
}
Would I change it to the following: {
  "directory": "bower_components"
}
Is there a command I can run to tell if the datepicker is installed?

Comment: I've just been doing a bit of reading. Are the datepicker files that are in bower components folder ("theme/bower_components/foundation-datepicker/") supposed to be getting copied over to my "js" folder ("theme/js") somehow?

Comment: I didn't get. You want your `foundation-datepicker.js` in the `theme/js` folder. If so then your `.bowerrc` file should look like the following - 
`{
  "directory": "theme/js"
}`
And `bower.json` file should mention the ` "dependencies": { foundation-datepicker: version}` along with other dependencies. You are telling that your `.bowerrc`  file looks as `{ "directory": "bower_components" } ` then the dependencies will be placed under `bower_components` folder not `theme/bower_components`.

Comment: After making your `bower.json` and `bowerrc` file correctly just run the following command `bower install`.

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that in my lack of experience in installing bower components to FoundationPress, that I was supposed to reference the files in the DOM myself once they had been downloaded using the 'bower install foundation-datepicker' command.

I have copied the files over to the suggested folders as in he README.md file and  referenced the files in the DOM. The datepicker feature is now working.

So in conclusion I did run 'grunt build' in my theme directory after the 'bower install foundation-datepicker' command, and I believe this was required based on the README.md.

Finally yes you do need to run 'grunt build' but only in your theme directory. But you need to refence the fils yourself in order to use them in your project.